# Inconsistent results saving png() and jpeg() in R

Tags: r, graphics, png, jpeg

I am saving some complicated graphs off in an R program that include `plot()`, `lines()`, `points()` and `abline()` function calls and have tried using both `png()` and `jpeg()`, but both are rendering very inconsistent results. In one run the grid will be saved in the background, in the next it will not. In one run, the points will be added at the correct `lwd`, in another they will be huge, or maybe not added at all. In another run, a line will added, and then disappear when I run it again. I am looping through hundreds of iterations, and getting different results with almost every run.

```
png(paste("/someFilePlace/pics/", propIn, ".png", sep = "")) 

plot(plotDat$yhat, col = "white", ylim = c(0,max(plotDat$yhat)*1.1),xaxt='n') 
fairlylightgray <- rgb(204/255, 204/255, 204/255, alpha=0.4) 
abline(v=(seq(0,1700,100)), col=fairlylightgray, lty="dotted") 
abline(h=(seq(0,10,0.5)), col=fairlylightgray, lty="dotted") 
points(plotDat$y, cex = '*', lwd = 3, col= "gray") 
lines(plotDat$yhat, col = "#08519C") 
axis(1, at = c(1,500,1000,1500), 
     labels = c(plotDat$dt[1],plotDat$dt[500],plotDat$dt[1000],plotDat$dt[1500])) 

dev.off()
```

Comment: You will need to include some code here if you want anyone to be able to really help you.

Comment: Are you using bitmap() in order to save into png and/or jpg? Are you working with ghostscript? Check this [link](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/dev2bitmap.html)

Comment: Here is the code. The results are also inconsistent printing to screen, so it is not only a rendering problem:

Comment: Where's the code? Stuff gets filtered out of comments, so edit it into your question.

Comment: png(paste("/someFilePlace/pics/", propIn, ".png", sep = "")) 
plot(plotDat$yhat, col = "white", ylim = c(0,max(plotDat$yhat)*1.1),xaxt='n')
fairlylightgray <- rgb(204/255, 204/255, 204/255, alpha=0.4)   
abline(v=(seq(0,1700,100)), col=fairlylightgray, lty="dotted")
abline(h=(seq(0,10,0.5)), col=fairlylightgray, lty="dotted")
points(plotDat$y, cex = '*', lwd = 3, col= "gray")
lines(plotDat$yhat, col = "#08519C")
axis(1, at = c(1,500,1000,1500), labels = c(plotDat$dt[1],plotDat$dt[500],plotDat$dt[1000],plotDat$dt[1500])) dev.off()

Comment: This is not reproducible by us (please see http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 ), and it's very surprising. Something has to be very badly wrong for R to be producing these kinds of non-deterministic results ... not that it should be behaving that badly anyway, but are you generating pseudo-random numbers in your code, or do you expect to be getting *exactly* the same results every time?

Comment: This pseudo-bug (failure to check for user error) is now fixed (by Duncan Murdoch) in the patched and development versions of R.  I'm still curious what you thought `cex="*"` would do, and why ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Congratulations, I think you may have found an obscure almost-bug (at least, failure to intercept a user error).  Try replacing `cex="*"` with something sensible in your code (it should be a number -- or maybe you meant `pch="*"`).

I am able to get different results in different PNGs as follows (if I plot in an X11 window I can get funny things to happen as I resize the window).

```
for (i in 1:10) { 
    png(paste("tmp",i,"png", sep="."))
    plot(1:10,1:10,cex="*"); 
    dev.off() 
}
```

Comment: That's truly bizarre.  FWIW, I also get odd effects of resizing when plotting to the GUI device in Windows.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I appreciate it. I was using the cex="*" notation to get scalable dots.

Comment: I will forward this to r-devel once I write a little bit more testing code. Jim: what were you trying to do, and where was it documented?  The `cex="*"` notation is not something I've ever seen ... the documentation in `?par` says "a numerical value ..." -- nothing about `"*"` as a possibility ...

Comment: Nice catch all around! I can reproduce the inconsistent behavior passing a character to `cex` in `plot`, but if I try `par(cex = "*")` I get an error.